# When building, isolatedModules is set to true, causing error: Option 'noEmitOnError' cannot be specified with option 'isolatedModules'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

In my typescript react-asp.net application (created in Visual Studio 2017), I receive the following error:

> Option 'noEmitOnError' cannot be specified with option 'isolatedModules'.

I set `isolatedModules` to `false` in `tsconfig.json`, but when the application is run, the `tsconfig.json` file is updated with `isolatedModules` set to `true` automatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here any fix

Comment: @Alen.Toma It has been a long time. I think I gave up on setting isolatedModules to false. Then, I addressed the typescript related errors.

Comment: @Alen.Toma: Were you able to resolve this issue?